# Subclass not inheriting method from Superclass

Tags: java

Here is the Subclass code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class deleteAfter extends BeginAgain{

public static void main(String[] args){
super.printed()
//I want to inherit the "printed()" method from my superclass, but 
//when I type "super.printed()" in my subclass's main method I get an error message that says 
//"Cannot use super in a static context"
//what am I doing wrong?
//Is it a compiler error or am I using "super" the wrong way?

};
}
```

Here's a link to the Superclass(BeginAgain.java) I put inside a JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/72cYy/70/

Maybe there's something wrong with the superclass that could be causing the problem.

Comment: I can tell you one thing you did wrong... you tagged a Java question as C++

Answer (score 3):

You can't call a non-static method from a static method.

You can call it by creating an instance first.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    deleteAfter instance = new deleteAfter();
    instance.printed();
}
```

You don't need the super keyword though.

You only need the super keyword if you want to extend the implementation of the `printed` method in your sub-class :

```
public void printed() {
    super.printed();
    // some additional logic 
}
```

Comment: thank you but I've seen a couple of examples use it that way, including this video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fs6bjAKqzYE

Comment: @user3081098 you need super.method() only if you are inside method() and want to call the same method in a super class. And this does not work in static.

Comment: @eckes thank you :) that clarified everything

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is exacly what the compiler tells you. Static methods are not associated with a particular class instance and therefore you cannot use a super keyword there